# label with regex- Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I'm trying to add a new label with regex.
the name instance is `pr-na01-na02-A`
I'm trying to get only the `pr-na01`,
so I did this:

```
  - source_labels: ['__meta_ec2_tag_Name']
    regex: '^[^-]*-[^-]*'
    target_label: 'test'
    replacement: '$1'
```

and still don't see a new label (test) under Prometheus metrics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you have no capture groups, so `$1` is empty. Also you're not matching the full string.

Try `(^[^-]*-[^-]*).*` as the regex.